# Why do I sometimes get undefined in the 'mail' property when I use the Microsoft graph /me endpoint?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to debug an issue in an existing product. It uses Microsoft 365's /me endpoint to get the logged in user's information.

The bug is sometimes depending on the email address the 'mail' property in the response is undefined.

I've seen this in 3 different microsoft accounts:

1. An @onmicrosoft.com email - This one returns a value in the 'mail' property
2. An @outlook.com email - This one returns undefined
3. A gmail address used to register in microsoft 365

This is the specific endpoint:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

And I believe this is the documentation for it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I would really like to know why this happens, and what I can do with it as I want to use the email addresses linked to these accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to repo the same with 3 different emails , 1st is microsoft.com (microsoft account) ,2nd onmicrosoft.com (microsoft sandbox account) and 3rd is outlook.com (personal account)

scenario 1 (microsoft account)
[image]

scenario 2 (microsoft sandbox account)
[image]

scenario 3 (personal account)
[image]

In both scenario 1 and 2 , its microsoft account and registered to azure portal , that why you can email property is updated , where as in the personal account  its not registered and those property where not update that's why you can see the null .

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful. Do you think I could use something else as a "mail" value for my system for example the userPrincipalName? Or is that unwise?

Comment: Thanks for the response , if you register your account on azure portal , it will update the mail value also .

Comment: If the answer was helpful , kindly upvote and mark it as verified , it will help others also .Thanks